Victory Native Tool Tip Disappearing
I have created a Cartesian chart in React Native using Victory Native in Javascript and added a tooltip.
Here is a link for reference from where I took the library.
https://commerce.nearform.com/open-source/victory-native/docs/
However the tooltip is disappearing automatically after a few seconds of moving it along the graph even if I haven't removed my finger from the screen. Can someone please guide me on how to fix this issue and how to add a second tooltip.
Here is my code for reference
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Text, Pressable, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Circle, useFont } from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
import { CartesianChart, Line, useChartPressState  } from "victory-native";

const DATA = Results.map((result, index) => ({
 day: index,
 close: result.Close,
}));

const FinalResult = () =>{
  const { state, isActive } = useChartPressState({ x: 0, y: { close: 0 } });
  
  function ToolTip({ x, y }) {
    return <Circle cx={x} cy={y} r={8} color="black" />;
  }

  return(
    <View style={{ height: 300, marginHorizontal:20 }}>
    <CartesianChart data={DATA} xKey="day" yKeys={["close"]} chartPressState={state}>
      {({ points }) => (
        <>
          <Line points={points.close} color="#0B588D" strokeWidth={1} />
          {isActive && (
          <ToolTip x={state.x.position} y={state.y.close.position} />
        )}
        </>
      )}
    </CartesianChart>
  </View>
  )

